# Getting column names from sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this table

```
id | apple | banana | coconut | pear| code | Class |
1     1       1       1           0    101      B
2     0       0        1          1    102      C
3     1       0        0          1    103      B
```

i have this query at the moment

```
select tree
from ((select id, 'apple' as tree
       from trees
       where apple = 1
      ) union all
      (select id, 'banana' as tree
       from trees
       where banana = 1
      ) union all
      (select id, 'coconut' as tree
       from trees
       where coconut = 1
      ) union all
      (select id, 'pear' as tree
       from trees
       where pear = 1
      )
     ) t
where id = 1;
```

which gives me output of

```
apple
banana 
coconut
```

but what i want to do is query it using `code`something like so
`WHERE code = '101' and id =1` and also for it to display the `class`
as output should be something like

```
   class  |fruits
     B      apple 
            banana  
            coconut
```

is something like this even possible.

let me know if you need any more clarification

Comment: `WHERE code = '101' and id =1` ...is `id` not unique? Because if it is, then `WHERE id=1` will do the job. But if you actually want to query just by the code, then leave the ID part out. It's unclear exactly what logic you're actually trying to implement. Also your data potentially looks denormalised - what happens when you need to add another type of fruit? You'd be better with a "class" table consisting of just the code and the class column, and then a "fruitClass" table which contains the ID from the "class" table and the fruit name (or better, the ID of the fruit from a "fruit" table)

Comment: that way you can support as many different fruits in each "class" as you like, and adding new fruit is just a case of adding a new row to the table, rather than changing your schema and having to alter all your queries. Any time you find yourself hard-coding names of things into columns or query clauses then it's probably time to consider if you could rationalise the schema a bit.

Comment: I feel like this is a homework question I've seen a couple of times already here on SO.

Comment: @dearsina stop thinking coz you are thinking wrong

Comment: @o3203823, you're right, it was another post by you from a few days ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954144/display-sql-query-output-for-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the column you need  and null in the select for union where you don't need  value

```
select tree
from ((select id, 'apple' as tree, code, class
       from trees
       where apple = 1
      ) union all
      (select id, 'banana' as tree, null, null
       from trees
       where banana = 1
      ) union all
      (select id, 'coconut' as tree, null,  null
       from trees
       where coconut = 1
      ) union all
      (select id, 'pear' as tree, null, null
       from trees
       where pear = 1
      )
     ) t
where id = 1;
```

in this way all the select have the same number of column  and matching data type